# SymPy - differentiate a somewhat twisted function

Tags: python, math, sympy

`diff ( (1/2) *  ( sqrt (x**2+x+1) - x )   - (4/2) * ln ( ( sqrt (x**2+x+1) - x )  +1) + (1/2) * ln (2* ( sqrt (x**2+x+1) - x )  -1) + (3/4) * (1/(2* ( sqrt (x**2+x+1) - x )  -1)) )`

I am trying to calculate this derivative with SymPy
but it gives me some expression more complicated than I expect.

I solved an indefinite integral by hand, and therefore I know the answer
to this should be `(sqrt(x**2+x+1)-1)/x`.

Wolfram Alpha also confirms it
(in WA one needs to just replace the `**` with `^`).

Here is the WA answer (see alternate forms):

[WA derivative](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate%20%28%20%281%2F2%29%20*%20%20%28%20sqrt%20%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%20-%20x%20%29%20%20%20-%20%284%2F2%29%20*%20ln%20%28%20%28%20sqrt%20%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%20-%20x%20%29%20%20%2B1%29%20%2B%20%281%2F2%29%20*%20ln%20%282*%20%28%20sqrt%20%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%20-%20x%20%29%20%20-1%29%20%2B%20%283%2F4%29%20*%20%281%2F%282*%20%28%20sqrt%20%28x%5E2%2Bx%2B1%29%20-%20x%20%29%20%20-1%29%29%20%29%20%20)

Is it possible to calculate and simplify this derivative with SymPy?
Or is this just a bit too much for SymPy?

Comment: Did you call .simplify() on the expression you get from the differentiation?

Comment: @Anonymous1847 Yes, of course but it didn't really work

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm the answer and it is possible to simplify it in sympy but the way to do it is not easy:

```
In [90]: d = diff ( (S(1)/2) *  ( sqrt (x**2+x+1) - x )   - (S(4)/2) * ln ( ( sqrt (x**2+x+1) - x )  +1) + (S(1)/2) * ln (2* ( sqrt (x**2+x+1) 
    ...: - x )  -1) + (S(3)/4) * (1/(2* ( sqrt (x**2+x+1) - x )  -1)) )                                                                        

In [91]: d                                                                                                                                     
Out[91]: 
                          ⎛    2⋅(x + 1/2)      ⎞         ⎛    x + 1/2        ⎞            2⋅(x + 1/2)                 
                        3⋅⎜- ─────────────── + 2⎟       2⋅⎜─────────────── - 1⎟          ─────────────── - 2           
                          ⎜     ____________    ⎟         ⎜   ____________    ⎟             ____________               
                          ⎜    ╱  2             ⎟         ⎜  ╱  2             ⎟            ╱  2                        
     x + 1/2              ⎝  ╲╱  x  + x + 1     ⎠         ⎝╲╱  x  + x + 1     ⎠          ╲╱  x  + x + 1               1
───────────────── + ───────────────────────────────── - ──────────────────────── + ──────────────────────────────── - ─
     ____________                                   2           ____________         ⎛            ____________    ⎞   2
    ╱  2              ⎛            ____________    ⎞           ╱  2                  ⎜           ╱  2             ⎟    
2⋅╲╱  x  + x + 1      ⎜           ╱  2             ⎟    -x + ╲╱  x  + x + 1  + 1   2⋅⎝-2⋅x + 2⋅╲╱  x  + x + 1  - 1⎠    
                    4⋅⎝-2⋅x + 2⋅╲╱  x  + x + 1  - 1⎠                                                                   

In [92]: f = sqrt(x**2 + x + 1)                                                                                                                

In [93]: f                                                                                                                                     
Out[93]: 
   ____________
  ╱  2         
╲╱  x  + x + 1 

In [94]: d.subs(f, y)                                                                                                                          
Out[94]: 
      2⋅(x + 1/2)      ⎛     x + 1/2⎞     ⎛    2⋅(x + 1/2)⎞              
 -2 + ───────────    2⋅⎜-1 + ───────⎟   3⋅⎜2 - ───────────⎟              
           y           ⎝        y   ⎠     ⎝         y     ⎠   1   x + 1/2
────────────────── - ──────────────── + ─────────────────── - ─ + ───────
2⋅(-2⋅x + 2⋅y - 1)      -x + y + 1                        2   2     2⋅y  
                                        4⋅(-2⋅x + 2⋅y - 1)               

In [95]: ratsimpmodprime(d.subs(f, y), [minpoly(f, y)]).subs(y, f)                                                                             
Out[95]: 
   ____________    
  ╱  2             
╲╱  x  + x + 1  - 1
───────────────────
         x
```

It looks like the `ratsimpmodprime` function isn't listed int he documentation but you can see it here:
https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/524fa229306898fded1d477017e0a88048d88c6b/sympy/simplify/ratsimp.py#L33

Comment: I opened https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/20236 and https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/20235 for the fact that ratsimpmodprime is not documented and that there should also be a more user-friendly way to use it.